# How to override TextTheme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In flutter TextTheme have 13 TextStyles:

- headline1,
- headline2,
- headline3,
- headline4,
- headline5,
- headline6,
- subtitle1,
- subtitle2,
- bodyText1,
- bodyText2,
- caption,
- button,

But my requirement is to add new TextStyle with name `bodyText3` and `subtitle3` in my project.

So that I can use in my widget like:

```
Text(
      'Body Text 3',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText3,
    )
```

**how could I do this in Flutter?**

Answer (score 0):

See what can you do is use `copyWith` in the theme what it will do is it will only change the property in the theme you want and rest keep the default theme so now here you can mention your customization and you will achieve your results
Example:

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText3: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
        ),
      ),
```

After mentioning here you can then use this and it will work

```
Text(
  'Body Text 3',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText3,
)
```

Similarly you can also change `subtitle3` just mention it in copyWith

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a class to hold your style and then call it from
> anywhere in your app.
>
> ```
> class CustomTextStyle {
>   static TextStyle bodyText3(BuildContext context) {
>     return Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(fontSize: 192.0);
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own textStyle by variable
`const bodyText3 = TextStyle(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try create a class *TextThemeCustom* extend from *TextTheme* and define your textStyle *bodyText3*

With *TextTheme*, create a extension with named bodyText3 and check:

If current object is *TextThemeCustom*
=> cast to *TextThemeCustom* and return *bodyText3*

Else return fallback for *bodyText3*: *bodyText2*

Comment: But i think if you choose Flutter for develop, you should maping your design with Material. Many widget  on Material design using default Texttheme.